# Regular expression in GWT

Tags: regex, gwt

help me please solve my little problem. I have a String

String str="aaa bbb ccc-ddd"

I simply want to change each word to start with upper case letter like this

"Aaa Bbb Ccc-Ddd"

Here is my code,

```
String[] r = str.split(" -");
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                result += r[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        .concat(r[i].substring(1))
                        + " ";
                System.out.println(result);
            }
```

but probably I wrongly write the regular expression in split method. So I always get the following result

"Aaa bbb ccc-ddd".

My delimeters are only space and dash. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're splitting on "a space followed by a dash", not "either a space or a dash", which would be `[ -]` (be careful when adding new delimiters, the dash has a special meaning inside brackets, so it has to appear at the beginning or end).

The rest of your code has issues though:

- `String#toUpperCase()` is locale-dependent in the JVM (i.e. if you use your code on the server-side too, or possibly if GWT later mimics the JVM) which means it would turn `i` to `I` in most locales, but in Turkish for example it would be `İ`. GWT 2.7 introduces support for `Locale.ROOT`, `Locale.ENGLISH` and `Locale.US` for those situations where you don't expect the result to vary depending on the current locale, so you can now use `.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)` to be locale-insensitive. Also note that `Character.toUpperCase` does not suffer from this problem.
- you concatenate with a space, so the result would be `Aaa Bbb Ccc Ddd`, not `Aaa Bbb Ccc-Ddd`.

Let's not talk about `System.out.println` as I suspect it's only there for debugging purposes.